Set a custom, dynamic icon for push notifications with expo
Looking for a way to set the icon of a notification on a per-notification basis, rather than for the icon of the application always. I'd like to allow the icon to represent the group where a notification is coming from, rather than just the normal app icon. An example of how this can be seen in Messages on iOS:

I'm currently using the expo-server-sdk to send notifications from Node, and have a React Native app that is handling notifications in the app frontend. I'm not sure this is possible with a RN app or with Expo, but couldn't find the exact case I'm working with discussed elsewhere. Thanks!
